# How to return first element of a group excluding NA's when non-NA values exist

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, grouping

I have a data frame named `df` which looks like.

```
x   y
A   NA 
B   d1
L   d2 
F   c1 
L   s2 
A   c4 
B   NA
B   NA
A   c1
F   a5
G   NA
H   NA
```

I want to group by `x` and fill in `NA` values with the first non-`NA` element in that group if possible. Note that some groups will not have a non-`NA` element so returning `NA` is fine for that case.

```
df %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(new_y = first(y))
```

returns the first value including `NA`'s even when non-`NA` values exist for that group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `replace`

```
df %>%
   group_by(x) %>%
   mutate(y = replace(y, is.na(y), y[!is.na(y)][1]))
#      x     y
#   <chr> <chr>
#1      A    c4
#2      B    d1
#3      L    d2
#4      F    c1
#5      L    s2
#6      A    c4
#7      B    d1
#8      B    d1
#9      A    c1
#10     F    a5
#11     G  <NA>
#12     H  <NA>
```

---

Or we can do a join in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
setDT(df)[df[order(x, is.na(y)), .SD[1L], x], y := coalesce(y, i.y),on = .(x)]
df
#    x  y
# 1: A c4
# 2: B d1
# 3: L d2
# 4: F c1
# 5: L s2
# 6: A c4
# 7: B d1
# 8: B d1
# 9: A c1
#10: F a5
#11: G NA
#12: H NA
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df$y <- with(df, ave(y, x, FUN = function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), x[!is.na(x)][1])))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(x = c("A", "B", "L", "F", "L", "A", "B", "B", 
 "A", "F", "G", "H"), y = c(NA, "d1", "d2", "c1", "s2", "c4", 
NA, NA, "c1", "a5", NA, NA)), .Names = c("x", "y"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```